# Active Page : Hover Status of Sprite

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

I am working with this page :
glustik.com/dustreeproductions/index.php

I am trying to make the "active-page" navigation show as such the "active-page".

I have a body ID tag of body_company in the markup.

Here is the CSS Rules for the first Nav Button : Company

```
background:url(../images/navigation/nav-company.png) no-repeat;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
width:103px;
margin:20px 27px 0 20px;
height:20px;}
#nav ul li#company a:hover {
background-position:0 -20px;}
#nav ul li#company a:active {
background-position:0 -40px;}
body #body_company #company a {
background-position:0 -40px;}
```

Relavant HTML Markup :

```
body id="body_company"
```

I have tried a few different things, cant seem to get it to show an active state when its on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between `body` and `#body_company`, it should be:

```
body#body_company #company a {
```

or just:

```
#body_company #company a {
```

**Edit:** An additional problem: The selector for the "normal" state `#nav ul li#company a` has a higher specificity / value than the active selector:

```
#nav ul li#company a
```

scores higher in the cascade than:

```
body#body_company #company a
```

So you would have to use:

```
#company a    /* for the normal state */
```

or something like:

```
body#body_company #nav #company a    /* for the active state */
```

I would recommend just using `#company a` for the normal state, if your ID's are unique (they should be anyway...), that´s specific enough.

Comment: I have changed it to "#body_company #company a {" but it still does not seem to work. I have tried many variations of this line of code. Anything else it could be?

Comment: @Varazi There's also the problem of specificity, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you Very Much. I have it fixed now. Had to follow your instructions and fix a few subsequent mistakes of my own (markup-flow).